# How to get input from textarea in html to .ts in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am a newbie in Angular and now I want to get user input from a textarea but I fail to do so.

Updated: ng-model="num1" > [(ngModel)]="num1"

HTML:

```html
<span><input [(ngModel)]="num1" type="text" placeholder="Enter value"></span>
     // user enter one number

<span><input type="text" readonly value={{answer}}></span></p>

<button class="result" (click)=onSelectEqual()>=</button>
     // click this button to get the value that user entered
```

.ts:

```
num1 : number;
answer: number;

onSelectEqual(){
  this.answer = this.num1 + 1 ;
}
```

Comment: Is it angular or angularJS? In angular you have to use `[(ngModel)]="num1"`

Comment: you are mixing `angular` and `angularJS`. The `click` event is called using angular syntax. In angularJS,  it should be `ng-click="onSelectEqual()"` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick.

Comment: A gentle reminder:   AngularJS == versions 1.x; Angular  == versions 2+. There is no such thing as AngularJS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of ng-model in your html template. ng-model is the syntax of Angularjs which will not work in Angular2+.

Also make sure to import `FormsModule` in app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Also add it to the imports array in app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
```

This is important as without the FormsModule, angular will not be able to identify the ngModel directive.

On a different note, the input will return the value typed by the user as a string. To read it as a number and add 1 to it, you will have to typecast it:

```
onSelectEqual(){
  this.answer = Number(this.num1) + 1 ;
}
```

Please also note that `//` for comments doesn't work in html template, use `<!-- -->` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In angular, for `two-way binding` you have to enclose `ngModel` in `[()]`. See - https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel.

`<span><input [(ngModel)]="num1" type="text" placeholder="Enter value"></span>`